# java get price and symbol

Tags: java, regex, currency

I have a string containing prices of items. How do i extract all the prices in the text in a situation where the currency symbol is not known at first.

```
I got a wristwatch for $500 and i could sell it to a Nigerian for ₦13,000 or to someone in Saudi Arabia for ﷼800
```

How do i get all the prices and their currency symbols.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  It's a pretty trivial regex, you just need a couple wild card values.

Comment: You seem to know you need regex. Have you tried it? Match for any of the allowed currency symbols and any number of numbers directly after them.

Comment: @keyser5053: Yes i can do it with regex. But what do i do in a situation where i need to match a symbol like the Afghanistan afghani. I am finding it difficult to copy that one into the editor.

Comment: @Nedy - see my answer let unicode character class handle the currency symbols

Comment: @sw1nn -Thanks, i am taking a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a regular expression character class for currency symbols:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// (incomplete) list of currency symbols, enhance from http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf
private static final String CURRENCY_SYMBOLS= "\\p{Sc}\u0024\u060B";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[" +CURRENCY_SYMBOLS + "][\\d,]+");

    Matcher m = p.matcher("I got a wristwatch for $500 and i could sell it to a Nigerian for " +
            "₦13,000 or to someone in Saudi Arabia for ﷼800 or Afghanistan for ؋350");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
 }
}

//Output is:
// $500
// ₦13,000
// ﷼800
// ؋350
```

Comment: I tried it on the above string an it worked. However, doesn't extract prices with latin symbols e.g دج , .د.ب etc

Comment: yes, that's quite annoying. you will have to enhance the regex with all the currency symbols, from one of the other answers - http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf gives you the list. I'll enhance the code above to illustrate.

Comment: This is great. All i need do is add more currency symbols. Thank you :D

Comment: I had to match decimals such as $500.50 as well. For that, use `("[" +CURRENCY_SYMBOLS + "][\\d,]+[\\.]+[\\d]+")`

Comment: you're allowing ``123....23`` which you probably don't mean. Having said that an exhaustive regex to allow ``123,232,324.34`` but not a variant like ``123,,232...34`` is quite painful.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding the currency symbols to the string, you could use `\u20a6` in the string for Nigerian currency and `\ufdfc` in the string for Saudi Arabian currency.

Comment: the \uXXXX notation is effectively a pre-processor directive, processed before compilation, so as far as the compiler is concerned \u20a6 and ₦ are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on a small function using regex to get price amount inside a String :

```
private static String getPrice(String input)
{
    String output = "";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}[,\\.]?(\\d{1,2})?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        output = matcher.group(0);
    }

    return output;
}
```

this seems to work with small price (0,00 to 999,99) and various currency :

$12.34 -> 12.34

$12,34 -> 12,34

$12.00 -> 12.00

$12 -> 12

12€ -> 12

12,11€ -> 12,11

12.999€ -> 12.99

12.9€ -> 12.9

£999.99€ -> 999.99

...

Answer (score 1):

For the string above, first you can simply parse for spaces, then if they contain digits get the result.

```
    String[] strArr = givenString.split(" ");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s : strArr){
        if(Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(s).find())
            result.add(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has syntax to write all the [Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) symbols it can handle, the syntax looks like '\uffff'

Unicode symbols are quite carefully defined so that related groups can be found. This says its a list of all [Unicode currency symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf)

Armed with those Unicode symbols in a regex, you could find money anywhere :-)

The Oracle (née Sun) documentation on [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has a whole set of character classes which include currency.

I do not know which version of Unicode is *actually* implemented. The reference I found at Oracle was "The supported blocks and categories are those of The Unicode Standard, Version 3.0". which according the the [Unicode group](http://unicode.org/versions/components-pre4.html#Unicode_3_0_0) was September, 1999, so that is what I'd assume.

This does include GBP £ and Euro € so I am okay :-) but it might not be up-to-date, though humanity don't invent currencies too often.

It would be a bit tedious, but you could generate a string with every character code (one at a time), and test for a match to the regex currency symbols, and check that ones that you particularly care about are included.

There is actually a further problem. Different countries use different marks for the decimal point, and some countries put the symbol after the amount. So far I haven't found a great solution to that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185793/how-do-i-get-the-currency-symbol-of-a-currency-as-it-would-appear-in-one-of-its) has no good answer.

So you might need to look for a number on either side of the currency symbol.